# Setting environment variables at runtime in KDE4

Tags: kde, environment-variables, kde4

Is it possible to set an environment variable at runtime, affecting all the programs started from the DE after that point (Desktop Environment, in my case KDE4) (without rebooting)?

I know it it possible to set system-wide or user-wide environment variables in `.profile`, `/etc/environment`, etc., but logging out and back in is required before they are read.

My aim is to store the current display resolution in 2 environment vars named `XRES` and `YRES` and update them when I switch to the secondary display.

Comment: no txtspeak plz. kthxbye

Comment: No it is not possible to update a running programs environment. It is possible to start a new shell with the new environment. @Gilles I suspect if you remove the KDE aspect this is a duplicate... do you know?

Comment: I took this question as meaning for programs newly started by the DE — i.e. change the environment of the launcher process. Indeed, if the question is updating the environment of already-running programs, the answer is a boring no. I'm editing the question accordingly.

Comment: eadmaster: if you want running programs to be informed of screen resolution changes, environment variables aren't the way to do it. Ask a new question about that, and tell us which programs you're interested in and how you want the programs to react.

Comment: ok, i can accept a "no" as answer... Btw i guess with root privileges it should be possible, even if i don't know any specific tool for that...

Comment: Well, I guess with root permissions, you could just write into the memory where the process's environment is stored.

Comment: @xenoterracide: That's not *entirely* correct: The process *itself* can update its environment (through `putenv`). And of course the process can provide an interface for you to do it as well (like e.g. `bash` does). Therefore the question really is: Does the KDE component responsible for launching new processes have an interface to change environment variables? I guess the answer will still be "no", but it's not a given.